# I am not able to get the output for this code. It seems like my functions are not called when onclick is used

Tags: javascript

Please help me understand why my on-click call is not invoking my function inside the script.

I tried different places to invoke onclick but still it doesn't seem to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    body {margin: 30px;}
</style> 
</head>
<body>


<form>
  Energy Spent in Hours:
  <input type="number" id="spent"/>
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="Calculate" id="calculate" onClick="start();"/>
</form>

  <p id="final"></p>


<script>

document.getElementById("calculate").onClick="start()";


function start(){
    x=document.getElementById("spent").value;

    if(x<50)
      document.getElementById("final").innerHTML="The hours are "+x+" multiplied with 3.5 is "calc(x,3.5);
    else
      if(x>50 && x<=150)
      document.getElementById("final").innerHTML="The hours are "+x+" multiplied with 4 is "calc(x,4);
      else
        if(x>150 && x<=250)
        document.getElementById("final").innerHTML="The hours are "+x+" multiplied with 5.2 is "calc(x,5.2);
        else
          if(x>250 && x<=500)
          document.getElementById("final").innerHTML="The hours are "+x+" multiplied with 6 is "calc(x,6);
          else 
          document.getElementById("final").innerHTML=1000;
}

function calc(z,y)
{
    return z*y;
}
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

I need to get the output of calculation on pressing calculate.

Comment: document.getElementById("calculate").onClick="start()"; is wrong

Comment: And it appears you have other syntax errors. Look at your developer console

Comment: You are not appending 'calc()` call correctly, add at least "+" before it, for ex. `.innerHTML="The hours are "+x+" multiplied with 3.5 is "+calc(x,3.5);`

Answer (score 2):

You have a bunch of syntax errors and you bind the event wrong and you had a bug with 50.

```js
function start() {
  x = document.getElementById("spent").value;

  if (x <= 50)
    document.getElementById("final").innerHTML = "The hours are " + x + " multiplied with 3.5 is " + calc(x, 3.5);
  else if (x > 50 && x <= 150)
    document.getElementById("final").innerHTML = "The hours are " + x + " multiplied with 4 is " + calc(x, 4);
  else if (x > 150 && x <= 250)
    document.getElementById("final").innerHTML = "The hours are " + x + " multiplied with 5.2 is " + calc(x, 5.2);
  else if (x > 250 && x <= 500)
    document.getElementById("final").innerHTML = "The hours are " + x + " multiplied with 6 is " + calc(x, 6);
  else
    document.getElementById("final").innerHTML = 1000;
}

function calc(z, y) {
  return z * y;
}

document.getElementById("calculate").addEventListener("click", start);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  Energy Spent in Hours:
  <input type="number" id="spent" />
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="Calculate" id="calculate" />
</form>

<p id="final"></p>
```